# I want to overlaod the operator '=' but after the overload the operator doesnt passes the right information to the object

Tags: c++, class, date, operator-overloading

i have written a class that is using operator overloading so i can initialze a date through a string. the parameters in the function are correct but after i pass them to an object there is unknown numbers in it (looks like an adress or somthing)

this is the class header:

```
    #include <iostream>;
    using namespace std;

    class Date {
    private:

    public:
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        Date();
        Date(int day, int month, int year);
        void Print(Date date);
        Date operator=(const string str);

    };
```

this is the cpp class file:

```
    #include "Date.h"
    Date::Date() {};
    Date::Date(int day, int month, int year) :
            day(day),month(month), year(year){};
    void Date::Print(Date date) {
        cout << date.day << "/" << date.month << "/" << date.year;
    }
    Date Date::operator=(string str) {
        Date date;
        date.day = 0; date.month = 0; date.year = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while(str[i] != '/'){
            date.day = (10 * date.day) + (int)str[i++]- 48;
        }
        i++;
        while(str[i] != '/'){
            date.month = (10 * date.month) + (int)str[i++]- 48;
        }
        i++;
        while(i < str.size()){
            date.year = (10 * date.year) + (int)str[i]- 48;
            i++;
        }
        cout << date.day << '/' << date.month << '/' << date.year<< endl;
        return date;
    }
```

and this is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {

    Date d,d2(15,7,18);
    string str = "15/7/18";
    d = str;
    cout << d.day<< endl;
    d.Print(d);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't modifying the currect object, instead you are modifying a variable called date. Remove the `date` variable from your overloaded operator. Like this

```
Date& Date::operator=(string str) {
    day = 0; month = 0; year = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '/'){
        day = (10 * day) + (int)str[i++]- 48;
    }
    ...
    return *this;
}
```

Also `operator=` should generally return a reference i.e. `Date&`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to change your `operator=` signature:

```
Date& operator=(const std::string& str);
```

In your implementation you are modifying local object of type `Date`, not the object for which the method has been called. You can modify it like this:

```
Date& Date::operator=(const std::string& str) {
    this->day = 0; this->month = 0; this->year = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '/'){
        this->day = (10 * this->day) + (int)str[i++]- 48;
    }
    i++;
    while(str[i] != '/'){
        this->month = (10 * this->month) + (int)str[i++]- 48;
    }
    i++;
    while(i < str.size()){
        this->year = (10 * this->year) + (int)str[i]- 48;
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << this->day << '/' << this->month << '/' << this->year<< std::endl;
    return *this;
}
```